# How can I build a SQL design, which provides Sub-Sub-Categories for products?

Tags: sql, categories, article, webshop

I'm trying to build a webshop-database and I have a problem, when it comes down to the design of a SQL-product table, which provides Sub Sub Categories.

For examle I have a main category, which is always set:

```
1.Cars
```

Then I have the first sub-category

```
1.1 BMW
1.2 Mercedes
```

And finally in some cases I have an even deeper category.

```
1.1.1 BMW M3
1.1.2 BMW M5

1.2.1 Mercedes 1
1.2.2 Mercedes 2
```

Currently I have three tables:

```
tbl_Article
int ArticleId
char Description
decimal Price
int Category
int SubCategory

tbl_Category
int CategoryId
char Description
int hasSubCategories

tbl_SubCategory
int SubCategoryId
int Category
char Description
```

How can I solve this problem, so that I can have multiple sub-categories if needed?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can design a "category-table", with an foreign-key on itself:

**tbl_category**

```
int   id                                            --primary key
int   fk_parentCategory REFERENCES tbl_category.id  --foreign key, can be null
char  description
...
```

**tbl_product**

```
int   id         --primary key
int   category   --foreign key, can not be null
char  name
...
```

The column `fk_parentCategory` is an foreign-key, pointing on its own table (but a different category). It can also be null.

If null, it's a top-category. If not, its a subcategory.

You only have to care, that a category never points to itself. So the column `id` must never have the same value as the column `fk_parentCategory`.